# CE Image + AWS usage

Tags: ce-image, aws

I'm probably being a bit dim, but how do you use CE Image with AWS?

I've added the CE Image and the CE Image - AWS plugins, and added the AWS config stuff, what next, I expected to see new field types or something?

How do fields know they should upload to AWS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ce img is not a fieldtype where you can expect any fields. It is image cropping and scaling plugin. AWS is a different plugin which gives you ability to upload/fetch images to/from bucket.

Implementation is pretty simple. Suppose you have a file field (image) in entry. At frontend template you will write something like this:

```
<img src="{image_field}" />
```

This will give you original Image. Now with CE Image, You will write something like this:

```
{exp:ce_img:single src="{image_field}" width='100' height='100' crop="yes" quality="75" cache="no" overwrite_cache="yes" allow_scale_larger="yes" attributes='class="ce_image"'}
```

I have added most common parameters but required paramter is only `src=''`

To implement AWS, You just have to add one more parameter: `bucket="myBucketName"` and image will start uploading and fetching bucket URLs.

I suggest you to go through documentation here: https://docs.causingeffect.com/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/variables.html#aws-url

Comment: I missed that extra bit of documentation, ce should link it to the other 'CE Image - AWS' documentation

Comment: yah. Its a pretty big documentation in a single page. Kinda boring too. I wish they have separate documentation in pages. Common, Pair, Crop, Scale, AWS etc.

Comment: {aws_url} is empty, I already have images on the site, I tried resyncing the directory in the hope that would upload to aws, i guess it didn't.

Comment: Check your backend aws settings once more